# Doing something while waiting for a Task to complete

Tags: c#

I'm trying to understand asynchronous methods. But once I attempt to do something while awaiting, such as writing to the console, `.IsCompleted` never becomes `true`.

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...
    //Object, event
    submitTag.Click += (o, e) => DoWork("www.google.com");
}

public async void DoWork(string _url)
{
    Task<int> task = GetAgeAsync(_url);
    //Some indicator
    while (!task.IsCompleted) Console.WriteLine("Loading");
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    DisplayAge(await task); //Pass result once it's done
}

public async Task<int> GetAgeAsync(string _url)
{
    int age = 0;
    if (_url != null)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => 
        {
            Task.Delay(5000).Wait(); //Some long process
            age = 20;
        });
    }
    return age;
}

public void DisplayAge(int _age)
{
    if (_age == 0) return;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} years old", _age);
}
```

Which endlessly outputs `Loading`, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You just need to `await task` the rest of that code doesn't do anything. Async != multithreaded

Comment: It works for me. What is the code that Task.Run executes?

Comment: Your code does not compile, so while I compensated when testing myself, I wonder what your actual code is and if the problem is not apparent because that is not the actual code you are running.

Comment: @Crowcoder Oh sorry, I'll take a look again. I did a little bit of simplifying for the post

Comment: `int age = null;` this is nonsense. An `int` _cannot_ be `null`... (just to start with).

Comment: @Fildor My bad just an oversite of the simplification of my program

Comment: in GetAgeAsync , throw out the Task.Run and just do `await Task.Delay(5000);` to simulate work.

Comment: @Fildor I'm still just seeing endless `Loading` in the output, by doing exactly that

Comment: `I attempt to do something while awaiting` - but the code is not doing something while awaiting. It's doing something while spin-waiting, and that is causing a deadlock. Replace `while (!task.IsCompleted) Console.WriteLine("Loading");` with `Console.WriteLine("Loading"); await task;` and it will work.

Comment: @StephenCleary I appreciate that that works, but it doesn't repeatedly output `Loading` (or do work), while waiting for the task to complete. It will output once, then wait for the task to be completed

Comment: @Luc: What's your real requirement? This is an odd mix of Console and UI approaches.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary At the moment, I'm just using the button UI as a trigger and testing this async method using the Console. I'm looking to show some continuous indication that a task is doing work

Comment: @Luc: Like, say, a spinner? That's a pretty normal approach, and you just need to `ShowSpinner(); try { await task; } finally { HideSpinner(); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A important point is that everything after `await` will need to run on the same 'context' as before await. In practice this means that `return age` will need to run on the main thread. For this to work the main thread need to be free, i.e. it needs to process windows messages and not be blocked by user code.

Running `while (!task.IsCompleted)` will never free the main thread to complete the task, i.e. a classic deadlock. This is also a frequent problem when using `Task.Result`

To solve the problem, just remove the While-loop. If you want to provide feedback you could start a timer to do the printing, and stop it after the task has completed. Another alternative would insert a `await Task.Delay(1000)` in the loop-body, this should give the main thread a chance to do other things. I would not recommend inserting a delay for production code however. In any real situation a progress-bar would probably be the appropriate solution, but that is a bit out of scope for the question.

Comment: There is no deadlock here. You will not block anything by looping until a task is complete because that is the point of asynchrony. If it were necessary to introduce a delay in order to provide waiting feedback then the framework would not be very useful.

Comment: This is a [deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). It's just not obvious.

Comment: @StephenCleary I guess you would know, but your article (which I have read many times) does not explain it to me. There is no `.Result` in the code. I still don't understand how this is a deadlock as I understand it. Do you have another resource?

Comment: @JonasH if you edit your question I'll give the vote back, but I still disagree with the advice of introducing a delay.

Comment: @Crowcoder: `Result` blocks the current thread until it completes. The code here is busy-waiting `while (!task.IsCompleted)` which also blocks the current thread until it completes.

Comment: @Crowcoder This is a deadlock since the main thread is waiting for the task to complete, and the task is waiting for the main thread to be free to run the continuation. The delay would simply be a point to yield control, letting the main thread pump messages and running the task-continuation. I agree that inserting a delay is not the best thing, but I hope it should illustrate what is going on.